# ScrollView above Map

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I wanna have a `ScrollView` above a map. The content of the `ScrollView` should start at 2/3 of the screen so I can see the markers on the map and use the map. But when I start dragging the scroll view it should use the whole height to scroll and not just the 1/3 where the `ScrollView` is.

I tried positioning with top which let me use the map but scrolling happened just inside the small area left. `paddingTop` has the desired effect but it didn't let me use the map of course.

How can I achieve what I want?

[image: Screenshot]

```
  clubResultContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    paddingTop: (Dimensions.get('window').height / 3) * 2,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    zIndex: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
```

Comment: Max Tommy Mischke did you get it done? If yes can you share how you did?

Answer (score 0):

try to add flexDirection: 'row' on your stylesheet